# Decision tree or rule

Tags: classification

What criteria can be used to decide whether to develop a decision tree or one or more rules using [oneR](http://search.r-project.org/library/FSelector/html/oneR.html) or jRip(contained in [RWeka](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RWeka/RWeka.pdf)). The similarities between these two algorithms (decision tree and rule) is very high making it a little confusing.

Comment: What are oneR and jRip? Haven't heard them before. Can you explain a bit and add some details to your question?

Comment: These are functions in R. OneR makes a single classification rule. While jRip will make as many rules as necessary

Comment: Let me know if my edit helps?

Comment: Cool. No problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JRip implements a propositional rule learner, “Repeated Incremental Pruning to Produce Error Reduction” [(RIPPER)](http://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/pdf/algorithm/congreso/slipper.pdf), as proposed by Cohen (1995) and OneR builds a simple [1-R classifier](http://www.mlpack.org/papers/ds.pdf), proposed by Holte (1993).

Its hard to say which algorithm works better. Best approach is to compare different classification algorithms performance in terms of precision, recall, accuracy, f1 score, AUC, specificity and sensitivity on your train/test data set and pick the one that gives best results or use ensemble of top performing algorithms to build your final model.

There is a good white paper doing similar exercise of comparing different classification algorithms including OneR and JRIP [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273015702_Applying_Naive_bayes_BayesNet_PART_JRip_and_OneR_Algorithms_on_Hypothyroid_Database_for_Comparative_Analysis).

Hope this helps.